# Jenkins: Scripts not permitted to use method org.thoughtslive.jenkins.plugins.jira.api.ResponseData getData

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jira

I have a pipeline (groovy file not declarative). The pipeline calls a function from shared library which uses [jira-steps-pulgin](https://jenkinsci.github.io/jira-steps-plugin) as follows:

```
withEnv(["JIRA_SITE=${jiraSite}"]) {
     testissue = [fields: [ project: [key: 'ISSUE'],
         summary: "Subject",
         description: "Test Test",
         issuetype: [name: 'Task']]]
     def response = jiraNewIssue issue: testissue
     currentIssueKey = response.data.key
     echo response.data.toString()
     ...
```

When the pipeline runs, an issue is created. But I also try to assign the issue to a user and therefore the functions gets the issue key as follows

```
currentIssueKey = response.data.key
```

This unfortunately fails with this error

```
Scripts not permitted to use method org.thoughtslive.jenkins.plugins.jira.api.ResponseData getData
```

I would have expected to approve this signature under script approval but there is not. How can I make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The respective method can be added directly to the scriptApproval.xml as follows

```
<string>method org.thoughtslive.jenkins.plugins.jira.api.ResponseData getData</string>
```

I had to restart Jenkins as "Reload Configuration from Disk" was not sufficient